# Drawing Line in PCL 1.2

Tags: point-cloud-library

Does any one know how can I draw a line between two defined points in pcl 1.2?
I know there are some ways like "addline" instruction in pcl 1.8 but what about pcl 1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addline function shows up in the documentation for PCL 1.2 (see link below). There are two ways to addLine. One using model coefficients, the other using points. The below code example is copied from that documentation for model coefficients.

```
 // The following are given (or computed using sample consensus techniques)
 // See SampleConsensusModelLine for more information
 // Eigen::Vector3f point_on_line, line_direction;

 pcl::ModelCoefficients line_coeff;
 line_coeff.values.resize (6);    // We need 6 values
 line_coeff.values[0] = point_on_line.x ();
 line_coeff.values[1] = point_on_line.y ();
 line_coeff.values[2] = point_on_line.z ();

 line_coeff.values[3] = line_direction.x ();
 line_coeff.values[4] = line_direction.y ();
 line_coeff.values[5] = line_direction.z ();

 addLine (line_coeff);
```

This is the syntax used for points

bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addLine (   const P1 &  pt1, const P2 & pt2, const std::string & id = "line", int viewport = 0)

Definition at line 577 of file pcl_visualizer.hpp.

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.2.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a5fd2b99b85da61df8b58980bdb6b0f41

Comment: In case you get a compilation error related to `getVector3fMap` while using a method based on `pcl::ModelCoefficients` then go to this link: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1029